# How can I invoke console.log and console.log() simultaneously with .on?

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to format the console.log() of an event returned, but I can't figure out how to invoke it console.log and console.log() together.

`.on("transactionHash", console.log)`

This works normally, and returns a transaction hash with no formatting.

`.on("transactionHash", function(){console.log('*** Tx Hash:', console.log, '***') })`

This prints the strings, but doesn't print the hash. If you use `console.log()` without declaring a function, it is an error. How can I use both of these with `.on` simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the callback accepts arguments, and apply `console.log` with the arguments. It also doesn't make sense to log the `console.log` function itself, you probably want to leave that out:

```
.on("transactionHash", function(...args){
  console.log('*** Tx Hash:');
  console.log.apply(console, args);
});
```

If you know that there's only going to be one argument (or a particular number of arguments), then:

```
.on("transactionHash", function(arg){
  console.log('*** Tx Hash:');
  console.log(arg);
});
```

Comment: I get ```*** Tx Hash: [Function: bound consoleCall] ***```, which is what I also get in my example above. An error event also occurs. 

The event is with Web3.js method ```web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction()```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to log the `console.log` function itself, you probably want to drop that completely

Comment: How can I set console.log to a variable then? I just want to print the hash with formatting.

Comment: What sort of special formatting are you looking for? You can assign `console.log` to another variable if you want, `const log = console.log`, but that doesn't accomplish much

Comment: I just want consistency in output. I can use .on twice, but then it's not on the same line. I tried:

```.on("transactionHash", function(){const log = console.log})
  .on("transactionHash", function(){console.log(log)})```
It outputs and error.

Comment: If you want them to be logged on the same line, then concatenate the strings together as desired, eg `console.log('Hash: ' + arg)`